# Protocol for VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, protocols, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Need to get port opened on vps server by the server company. The port is for VisualSvn so i can connect to it from my pc.

Question is, what is the protocol for this traffic,
TCP
UDP
ICMP
IP
??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP.

Check which ports your VIsualSVN installation is using in the setup dialog.

The defaults are (from [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/)):

> Standard HTTP and HTTPS ports are now defaults: VisualSVN Server suggests to use the standard 80 and 443 ports by default (instead of 8080 and 8443 ports as in previous versions).